# Outline View Horizontal Grid customization in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

Is there a way to customize the outline View so that only expandable rows have borders.
Currently the default horizontal grid applies borers across all rows.

[image: Horizontal Grid Settings]

[image: Horizontal Grid Look]

When I try to apply a border to the expandable row as u can see in image below it excludes the disclosure triangle.

[image]

[image: Outine View Expandable Cell Border]

I want the disclosure triangle to also be inside the border. How do I achieve that?

Comment: How is the border implemented?

Comment: Which view has a border, a cell view or the row view?

Comment: The cell view has the border.

Comment: have you tried a border on the row view?